# React Router 4 with Typescript, Redirect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I tried to write some routing in my app using typescript, but I have a problem with redirect component. This is my code:

```
export interface Props {

}

const Routes = (props:Props) => (
<Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}/>

    <Redirect   to="/login" component={Login}/>

</Switch>
);

export default Routes;
```

Then, the compiler throws the following error:

> (20,33): error TS2339: Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & ...'.

Could you tell me where is the problem or how can I do the redirection when url is not compare with my router ?

Comment: Remove the `component` prop in `<Redirect />`. Rendering a <Redirect> will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

Answer (score 1):

To see which properties you can set on the `Redirect` component you have to take a look at the type definition of the RedirectProps from @types/react-router

```
...
export interface RedirectProps {
  to: H.LocationDescriptor;
  push?: boolean;
  from?: string;
  path?: string;
  exact?: boolean;
  strict?: boolean;
}
...
```

this interface has no property defined for `component` and so the ts-compiler will throw an error for `component={Login}`.

It's also not very useful to give another component to a `Redirect`-element, because it only redirects to a new route and has no displayed value.